# A simple (trivial) c++ makefile on UNIX

Tags: makefile

I am trying to make a makefile for one cpp file. I've tried googling and none of the examples I've seen have helped... I keep getting errors when I type make. Here is what I have...

```
      Interpreter: Interpreter.o
           g++ -o Interpreter Interpreter.o

      Interpreter.o: Interpreter.cpp
           g++ -c Interpreter.cpp
```

When I type make I get this error... "'ake: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `Interpreter.o"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try removing that indentation.

Comment: How did you name your makefile? Try `make -f "your-makefile"` and check if you used actual tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: The name is "makefile" ...are tabs bad in makefiles?

Comment: make -f makefile doesnt work either

Comment: No, tabs are good :) In fact, spaces are bad. Your targets must not be preceded by spaces or tabs, the rules (`g++ ...`) must be preceded by at least one tab.

Comment: Works for me, remove the  indentation before the first and third line, the second and fourth must be indented with exactly one tab.

Comment: Ok it works now... I had no idea that makefiles were so funny about spaces and tabs...

Answer (score 1):

OK. A few simple things to start with here:

- As mentioned in some of the comments, the makefile file must be named properly for make to find it. You can try specifing it manually with the `-f` flag to verify that it is being found.
- Make is one of those few unfortunate languages where whitespace is important. The rules must not have a tab in front of them, and the commands for the rules should all have exactly **one** tab in front of them. When I checked your code above in the SO editor, it looked like your commands had *two* tabs at the front instead of one.
- If I'm reading those rules right, you need a file named `Interpreter.cpp` in your working directory for this to work. If you don't have that file, you'll get an error.
- If all else fails, try running make with the debugging flag (`-d`). This should give you more information about the decisions it is making.